# Save Word file as HTML format using OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I have a code which saves Word file in HTML format using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.

Here is my code

```
void ConvertDocument(string fileName)
{
    object m = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    object oldFileName = (object)fileName;
    object readOnly = (object)false;
    ApplicationClass ac = null;

    try
    {
        // First, create a new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass.
        ac = new ApplicationClass();

        // Now we open the document.
        Document doc = ac.Documents.Open(ref oldFileName, ref m, ref readOnly,
            ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m,
             ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m);

        // Create a temp file to save the HTML file to. 
        tempFileName = GetTempFile("html");

        // Cast these items to object.  The methods we're calling 
        // only take object types in their method parameters. 
        object newFileName = (object)tempFileName;

        // We will be saving this file as HTML format. 
        object fileType = (object)WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML;

        // Save the file. 
        doc.SaveAs(ref newFileName, ref fileType,
            ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m,
            ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m, ref m);

    }
    finally
    {
        // Make sure we close the application class. 
        if (ac != null)
            ac.Quit(ref readOnly, ref m, ref m);
    }
}    

string GetTempFile(string extension)
{
    // Uses the Combine, GetTempPath, ChangeExtension, 
    // and GetRandomFile methods of Path to 
    // create a temp file of the extension we're looking for. 
    return Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),
        Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName(), extension));
}
```

I want to know how can i do this using OpenXML?

I have googled but didnt find relevant solution